# Carousel Bootstrap não funciona

Tags: bootstrap, carousel

Não está funcionando meu carousel em bootstrap, peguei este script do site www.w3schools.com importei o css e o JavaScript mas ele não funciona:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="fundo.png" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="fundo.png" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="fundo.png" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Na Head do HTML eu coloquei os Js:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reveja as bibliotecas que você está utilizando e verifique suas dependencias, no caso do bootstrap é necessário incluir a bibliotecar *jQuery* primeiro:

> **Bootstrap**
>
> Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If
> you include plugins individually, make sure to check for these
> dependencies in the docs. Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery
> (this means **jQuery** must be included **before** the plugin files).

[GetBootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/javascript/)

Essas são as bibliotecas utilizadas no exemplo que a *w3schools*:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Segue abaixo exemplo funcionando:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, muito noobisse da minha parte kkkk.. mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema é que vc está usando o Componente do **Bootstrap 3**, mas com os CDNs do **Bootstrap 4**

***E conforme o Caique falou o ideial é que o jQuery venha antes do JS do Bootstrap.***

Esse é o seu Head: bootstrap/4.0.0/css

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**Na verdade deveria ser assim:** bootstrap/3.3.7/css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Obrigado, muito noobisse da minha parte kkkk.. mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @DanielFortunato é muito comum vc procurar algo sobre Bootstrap no Google e ele te mostrar um link do BS3 ou BS4 sem muito critério. Então sempre preste muita atenção sobre qual dos dois vc está usando e para qual link o Google te sugeriu.

Comment: mais uma vez obrigado pela dica, fiz uma nova pesquisa e achei o mesmo exemplo só que com o bootstrap atualizado:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_carousel.asp